# Formula with multiple if or

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that automaticaly sees which person is linked to the number. person one has 0 and 1, person 2 has 2 and 3 ETC. The numbers are all 1 digit

I have tried

```
=IF(or(A2=0,A2=1),E2,OR(A2=2,A2=3);F2 ETC
```

but no succes.

I want a formula that displays which person is linked to the number

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your sheet?

Comment: In each `Else`-Case you need to wrap the next statement into a new `IF`-Block. I.e. `IF(OR(A2=0,A2=1),E2,IF(OR(A2=2,A2=3),F2,IF(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `number` is in A1:

```
=INT(A1/2)+1
```

Comment: Your approach will test the condition correctly but OP wants to return a range reference based on numeral.

Comment: Nice thought, maybe wrap it with `=INDEX(E2:F2,,INTEGER(A1/2)+1)` with `E2:....` whatever column is last.

Comment: Got this to work, made an extra formula that links the output of this formula to the correct person